# Get current location information using google current Place api

Tags: android, google-places-api

I want to get the all places at my location. I am using google current place api

```
private void getCurrentPlaceData() {
    mPlaceDetectionClient = Places.getPlaceDetectionClient(this);

    Task<PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse> placeResult = mPlaceDetectionClient.
            getCurrentPlace(null);
    placeResult.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse> task) {
            List<Place> placesList = new ArrayList<Place>();
            PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse likelyPlaces = task.getResult();
            for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                placesList.add(placeLikelihood.getPlace().freeze());
            }
            likelyPlaces.release();
            showAddPropertyNameDialog(AppStringConstants.ADD_NEW_STORE_TAG, placesList.get(0));
        }
    });
}
```

and included following in manifest file

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_map_key" />

  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I have written above method for it. 
Now the problem is ... it is working fine above 6.0 fine but not below this.

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 13: ERROR
```

and I have visited many links on this site no one helped.

Comment: have you add meta-data in manifest file?

Comment: update the question with your manifest code.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code in the `<application>` tag in your manifest file.

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="PASTE_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE" />
```

Comment: Have you enabled the following??

Google Maps Distance Matrix API
Google Places API Web Service
Google Places API for Android

Comment: And also as posted [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key) : **Reminder: To use the Places API, you must get an API key and you must enable billing. You can enable billing when you get your API key (see the Quick guide) or as a separate process (see Usage and Billing).** You must enable billing permission. `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />`

Comment: @RajneeshShukla are you testing it on a real device or emulator?

Comment: I have tested on mobile and emulator both

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187479/discussion-between-rajneesh-shukla-and-kartik).

Comment: are you getting the same error after trying?? @RajneeshShukla

Comment: You have to add Places SDK for Android under API restrictions. @RajneeshShukla

Comment: thanks @Kartik,  Its working now.  What I did...  I will show a alert dialog if  location permission is not given. It will open  permission screen and when user allow it is working fine

Comment: Glad to hear that :)